# Convert Float value to Hours and Minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

I have a `float` value, for example `0.999888`, which I am getting from SQL database.

I have a variable in vbscript assigned to the `float` value from the SQL.

Lets say that I have this, for example

```
Dim TimeInFloat
TimeInFloat = 0.999888
```

I want to convert it to the hours and minutes either in SQL itself or VBscript.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert it to hours and minutes in SQL by doing:

```
select floor(TimeInFloat * 24) as hours,
       60 * (TimeInFloat * 24 - floor(TimeInFloat * 24)) as minutes
```

You can do similar logic in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

In VBScript the [`CDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function allows you to convert float/double to time:

```
>>> WScript.Echo CDate(0.999888)
23:59:50
```